# Setting ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I am having trouble with listview and spinners. I am using a list view to display items and using a spinner to filter between categories and a button to refresh the view. My problem is that after selecting a different category it does not change the listView and reverts the spinner to the original category. I have tried using `.clear()` and an `onClickListener()` but my problem persists. Is there a way to make the spinner change the items in the listView after clicking the button?

```
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {

   private ListView menuList;
   private Spinner menuSpinner;
   private Button buttonRefresh;
   //private ArrayList<Menu> menuArrayList ;

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);
       Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView of MenuFragment has loaded");

       //menuApps=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.menuApps);
       //menuTitle=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.menuTitle);
       menuList=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.menuList);
       menuSpinner=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.menuSpinner);
       buttonRefresh=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonRefresh);

       //menuSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new View.OnItemClickListener());
       //menuViewingMethod();

               buttonRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               menuViewingMethod();
               Log.i(TAG,"Refresh has been clicked");
           }
       });

       return rootView;
   }


  public ListView menuViewingMethod(){
      List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
      list.add("Appetizers");
      list.add("Salads");
      list.add("Soups");
      list.add("Side Items");
      list.add("Entrees");
      list.add("Desserts");

      //sets up the spinner
      ArrayAdapter<String>dataAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
      dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
      menuSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


      String input= menuSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
      Log.d(TAG,input);
      if (input=="Appetizers"){
          //menuList.clear();
          /*menuList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
          menuArrayList.add("Gerst Sampler – $12.99");
          menuArrayList.add("Fried Oyster Basket – $11.99");
          menuArrayList.add("Gerst Ham Rolls - $11.99");
          menuArrayList.add("Bavarian Kraut Balls – $8.99");
          Log.i(TAG,"Spinner item Appetizers has been selected");*/
          String[] apps = new String[]{"Gerst Sampler – $12.99",
              "Fried Oyster Basket – $11.99",
              "Gerst Ham Rolls - $11.99",
              "Bavarian Kraut Balls – $8.99"};
           ArrayList<String> menuArrayList= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(apps));

           ArrayAdapter<String>arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menuArrayList);

          menuList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

      }
      //https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-listview-add-items.html

      else if (input=="Salads"){
          /*menuArrayList.clear();
          menuList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
          menuArrayList.add("Salad1");*/


          String[] salads = new String[]{"Salad1", "Salad 2", "Salad 3"};

           List<String> menuArrayList= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(salads));

           ArrayAdapter<String>arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,menuArrayList);

          menuList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
          arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }

      else if(input=="Soups"){
          /*menuList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
          menuArrayList.clear();*/
          String[] soups = new String[] {"Soup 1", "Soup 2", "Soup 3"};

           List<String> menuArrayList= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(soups));

           ArrayAdapter<String>arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menuArrayList);

          menuArrayList.clear();

          menuList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
          arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }



      String[] apps = new String[]{"Gerst Sampler – $12.99",
              "Fried Oyster Basket – $11.99",
              "Gerst Ham Rolls - $11.99",
              "Bavarian Kraut Balls – $8.99"};
       List<String> menuArrayList= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(apps));

       ArrayAdapter<String>arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menuArrayList);

      menuList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);



     // menuSpinner.setOnTouchListener((View.OnTouchListener) this);

       arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

      return menuList;
  }

}
```

Comment: It seems to me that everytime menuViewingMethod() is called, you reset the adapter of the menuSpinner at the top right before the first if statement. And at the end of the if/else logic in this same method, you're resetting the menuList to its default state. Move the "setup" code out of this method and outside the refresh btn click listener as you want that code to be the default state of your list and menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would suggest two things:

1. Relocate your spinner setup from 'menuViewingMethod()' to 'onCreateView()'. This is probably the cause of your spinner resetting to 0 every time the 'menuViewingMethod()' is triggered.
2. In 'menuViewingMethod()', make 'menuArrayList' and 'arrayAdapter' class variable and reload the list with new contents instead.

   String[] salads = new String[]{"Salad1", "Salad 2", "Salad 3"};
   menuArrayList.clear();
   menuArrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(salads));
   arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();